# MySQL is not accessible from public ip installed on linux

Tags: mysql, linux

I have debian linux system.I installed MySQL on it.I am not able to access it from public access. I edited /etc/mysql/my.cnf  and changed bind-address=127.0.0.1 to my server address and then restarted mysql service. But when I restart mysql service it is showing

Warning: World-writable config file '/etc/mysql/my.cnf' is ignored

How can I solve this ?

Comment: I think you need to `chmod o-w /etc/mysql/my.cnf`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now it is working fine. Steps I performed

Steps:-

1) SSH into VM instance.
2) Go to /etc/mysql directory using     cd /etc/mysql
3) Edit my.cnf file. By default the permissions are u=rw,g=r,o=r so we need to change its permissions to edit using

sudo chmod u=rwx,g=rwx,o=rwx my.cnf

4) Now edit this file using
vi my.cnf

5) Under [mysqld] directive change bind-address to 0.0.0.0
        bind-address=YOUR-SERVER-IP

6) Comment out the skip-networking 
          # skip-networking

7) Save my.cnf by pressing Esc and :wq and hit enter

8) Restart the Mysql service using 
          etc/init.d/mysqld restart

9) Login to mysql using
         mysql -u root -p mysql

10) Grant access to user using
       GRANT ALL ON *.* TO @'%' IDENTIFIED BY '';
where *.*  -> database_name.tables  (can provide access to particular database)
‘%’       -> IP_address (provide access to particular ip)

11) You need to open TCP port 3306 using iptables or BSD pf firewall using 
        /sbin/iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --destination-port 3306 -j ACCEPT

12) Add firewall rule on Google VM instance 
Project Name -> Compute Engine -> Network -> Click on default Network
Add firewall Rule like 
Provide any name and under Allowed protocols and ports -> tcp:3306;

13) Done

Answer (score 0):

Try flushing the privileges login as root and use MySQL; Database, something to do with the grant privilege

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

remove the old user entry for that user and do a direct INSERT for the user with the domain into user table.

```
insert into user (....) values (....)
```